# not able to redirect using handlerror

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect to error component when response data have "401" error and below is my code
but its not handling the error . I tried to redirect to external url but no luck.
Please guide , Thanks in Adavance

**Service.ts:-**

```
public searchGroups(searchReviewData: SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel): Observable<SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel> {
    this._urlSurveillanceDetails = this.baseHref + "/ReviewProfile/SearchGroups";
    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let getData = this.http.post<SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel>(this._urlSurveillanceDetails, searchReviewData, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
    return getData;
  }


  handleError(data: any) {
    if (data instanceof ErrorEvent) {

    }
    else {
      switch (data.errorResponse.httpStatusCode) {
       case 401:
       this.router.navigate(['error', 'unauthorized']);
         break;       

      }
    } 
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later:' + JSON.stringify(data.errorResponse.httpStatusCode));

  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
searchGroups(searchReviewData: SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel) {
    this._surveillanceService.searchGroups(searchReviewData).subscribe(data => {
      if (data != undefined) {
        this.reviewData = data;
        if (data.reviews != null) {
          if (data.reviews.length == 1) {                
            this.pagerSelectedData = data.reviews;
            this.loading = false;                

          }
        }
        else {
          this.loading = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

**ResponseJson from MVC controller:**

```
{
    "loggedInUser": {
        "v2020UserId": "kdevisenakanthan"
    },
    "errorResponse": {
        "errorCode": null,
        "transactionId": null,
        "httpStatusCode": 401
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will crash if it ever tries to execute the redirect. Never pass unbound methods as callbacks. Use an arrow function or `.bind`

Answer (score 0):

it seems to use `data.error instanceof ErrorEvent` and `data.status`

ant the docs here https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse

Comment: Thanks and I added the response json . i need to check the status inside "errorResponse" child object, please guide me